# Eclipse shows error icon to me but do not tell me what the errors are

Tags: android, eclipse

[image: YOU CAN SEE THE ERRORS WITH CROSS ENCLOSED BY RED RECTANGULAR]
YOU CAN SEE THE ERRORS WITH CROSS ENCLOSED BY RED RECTANGULAR
However I don't know what the problem is.
I tried to run the app to see what the errors are , but it couldn't run.
is there anyway to show what the errors are?
thanks in advance~ I'm not familiar with eclipse

Comment: There should be an **Problems** tab at the bottom. If something went wrong it will display the report.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean your project, Project -> Clean... -> Clean Projects. There are times when you copy paste, or alter the xml files that the project will need cleaned.